# How to update an entity with related data (arrays) from request/body custom objects with states (modified, added, removed) in EF Core 3+?

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, asp.net-core-3.1, entity-framework-core-3.1

Simplified versions of my objects:

```
public class CV 
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public List<Certificate> Certificates {get;set;}
  public List<Experience> Experiences {get;set;}
}
public class Certificate 
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
public class Experience 
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public List<SkillExperience> Skills {get;set;}
}
public class SkillExperience
{
  public int SkillId {get;set;}
  public int ExperienceId {get;set;}
  public bool isCore {get;set;}
}
public class Skill 
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

From request's body (from frontend) comes the following object (again really simplified):

```
public class CvRequest 
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public CertificateRequest Certificates {get;set;}
  public ExperienceRequest Experiences {get;set;}
}
public class CertificateRequest
{
  public List<Certificate> AddedCertificates {get;set;}
  public List<Certificate> ModifiedCertificates {get;set;}
  public List<int> RemovedCertificateIDs {get;set;}
}
// the ExperienceRequest is a little more complex because it has a many-to-many relationship, so I won't show it
// but it's similar, the question is related to it, but it has the same pattern of modified/added/removed
```

I have Generic Repository Pattern (architecture), so I loop through the List of Added entities and call conext.Set.Add(entity), I loop through the Modified and call Update, and I loop through the removed IDs and call Remove by ID.

### The problem/question:

The problem is that I access the CV with .Include(cv => cv.Certificate) and all of the related data this way. Then I call `cvRepository.Update(cvRequest.ToEntity<CV>());` and **it works**, but then when I call `certificateRepository.Update(new Certificate(){...});` it says this:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Certificate' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 5}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.
```

As it is related data to already tracked entity, I can't update it on its own. I can't cv.Certificates.Update(certificate) or something like this, I have access only to the DbSet directly. I tried to make the `{context_name}.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;` I also tried `AsNoTracking`.

What about the many-to-many? It's even worse there. There are deeper nesting and tracking management.

### What about this?

What's the best way to update Related Data of Entity (and related data of the related data) in EF Core 3+?

Should I use `{context_name}.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(modifiedEntity);` instead of `Update(modifiedEntity);` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue you are running into is that you try to track  a Certificate with the ID=5 a second time although it's already tracked with the call

```
certificateRepository.Update(new Certificate(){...});
```

Basically it's already loaded and tracked with *.Include(cv => cv.Certificate)* and you try to track it one more time by creating a new Object and calling Update on your repository.

In this case you could manipulate the Certificate which is loaded with the cvRequest and call SaveChanges without explicitly calling "Update" on a new object the entity. EF Core will manage the tracking for you and notice it was changed and update it.

Comment: Ok. Just one more question before I mark your answer as solution. It won't track if there is a missing entity in the List right? I should manually delete it, right? I don't understand when it makes the EntityState.Deleted.

Comment: Yeah if you want to delete the entity you have to manually delete it. If you delete the "parent" and cascade deletes, the children get delete as well so you don't have manually traverse the whole tree. It all depends on the setup you have there.